# How to use an NSAttributedString with a ScrollView in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, uikit, swiftui, nsattributedstring

I've been able to render `NSAttributedString`s via `UIViewRepresentable` which works great until I wrap the view in a `ScrollView`.

When placed inside the `ScrollView`, the `NSAttributedString` view stops rendering.

I've tried some other methods that replace an `NSAttributedString` with adding multiple `Text()` views together to get formatting which works inside the `ScrollView` and supports *italics* and `monospace font`. Unfortunately this doesn't work for [links](https://example.com) inside text blocks, which means I still need an `NSAttributedString`.

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct TextWithAttributedString: UIViewRepresentable {

    var attributedString: NSAttributedString

    init(_ attributedString: NSAttributedString) {
        self.attributedString = attributedString
    }

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UITextView {
        let textView = UITextView(frame: .zero)
        textView.attributedText = self.attributedString
        textView.isEditable = false
        return textView
    }

    func updateUIView(_ textView: UITextView, context: Context) {
        textView.attributedText = self.attributedString
    }
}


let exampleText = """
Fugiat id blanditiis et est culpa voluptas. Vivamus aliquet enim eu blandit blandit. Sit eget praesentium maxime sit molestiae et alias aut.
"""

struct NSAttributedStringView: View {
    var body: some View {
// Note: when uncommented, the view breaks
//    ScrollView {
        TextWithAttributedString(NSAttributedString(string: exampleText))
//    }
    }
}

struct NSAttributedStringView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        NSAttributedStringView()
            .previewLayout(.sizeThatFits)
    }
}
```

**Edit:** I tried using the wrapped `UITextView` with the `text` property set instead of the `attributeText` property, but this also fails to render in the `ScrollView`, so the issue seems to be the `UITextView`, not the `NSAttributedString`.

So the question is, how do we get the `UITextView` to work in a `ScrollView`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The reason is that SwiftUI `ScrollView` requires defined content size, but used `UITextView` is itself a `UIScrollView` and detects content based on available space in parent view. Thus it happens cycle of undefined sizes.

Here is a simplified demo of possible approach how to solve this. The idea is to calculate content size of `UITextView` and pass it to SwiftUI...

```
struct TextWithAttributedString: UIViewRepresentable {
    @Binding var height: CGFloat
    var attributedString: NSAttributedString

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UITextView {
        let textView = UITextView(frame: .zero)
        textView.isEditable = false
        return textView
    }

    func updateUIView(_ textView: UITextView, context: Context) {
        textView.attributedText = self.attributedString

        // calculate height based on main screen, but this might be 
        // improved for more generic cases
        DispatchQueue.main.async { // << fixed 
            height = textView.sizeThatFits(UIScreen.main.bounds.size).height
        }
    }
}


struct NSAttributedStringView: View {
    @State private var textHeight: CGFloat = .zero
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            TextWithAttributedString(height: $textHeight, attributedString: NSAttributedString(string: exampleText))
                .frame(height: textHeight) // << specify height explicitly !
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Works great! One minor addition I needed was to wrap the `height` assignment in a `DispatchQueue.main.async {` call, otherwise I would get a SwiftUI warning about setting state in render, with the resulting view being empty.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use [Asperi's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59891267/7475980) `TextWithAttributedString` as a child view, replace

```swift
height = textView.sizeThatFits(UIScreen.main.bounds.size).height
```

by

```swift
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    height = textView.sizeThatFits(textView.visibleSize).height
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This is almost perfect. the only problem is that when orientation changes, the height is not right. Do you have any way to address that?

Comment: Instead of using deprecated `UIScreen` bounds, you can determine the width of the view using `GeometryReader` in the enclosing view and pass it to `sizeThatFits`. 

Furthermore it adapts to width that are no as large as the screen, for example if you have a padding.