# UITextView and NSAttributedString is not showing in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview, nsattributedstring

I'm trying to use UITextView and NSAttributedString by UIViewRepresentable.
This is my code.

- AttrText is struct that contains text(String) and information about text color and font.

```
struct TextView: View {
  let attrTextList: [AttrText]
  let size: CGFloat
  let lineSpacing: CGFloat

  var body: some View {
    IntegratedTextView(attrTextList: attrTextList, alignment: .left, size: size)
        .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)
  }
}

struct IntegratedTextView: UIViewRepresentable {
  let attrTextList: [AttrText]
  let alignment: NSTextAlignment
  let size: CGFloat

  init(attrTextList: [AttrText], alignment: NSTextAlignment, size: CGFloat) {
    self.attrTextList = attrTextList
    self.alignment = alignment
    self.size = size
  }

  func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UITextView {
    let textView = UITextView()

    let result = attrTextList.map { text -> NSAttributedString in
          var attrString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: text.text)
          let attribute: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = [
            NSAttributedString.Key.font: processFont(text: text, size: size),
            NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: processColor(text: text)
          ]
          attrString.addAttributes(attribute, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: attrString.length))
          return attrString
        }
        .reduce(NSAttributedString(string: ""), +)

    textView.attributedText = result
    textView.textAlignment = alignment

    print("TextView: \(textView)")
    return textView
  }

  func updateUIView(_ textView: UITextView, context: Context) {
  }

  func processColor(text: AttrText) -> UIColor {
    //something return color by AttrText
  }

  func processFont(text: AttrText, size: CGFloat) -> UIFont {
    //something return font by AttrText and size
  }

}

extension NSAttributedString {
  static func +(left: NSAttributedString, right: NSAttributedString) -> NSAttributedString {
    let result = NSMutableAttributedString()
    result.append(left)
    result.append(right)
    return result
  }
}
```

I think it should work but it's not. The IntegratedTextView is invisible when I turn on app.
by `print("TextView: \(textView)")`, I checked console log and it prints like this.

```
TextView: <UITextView: 0x1351c3600; frame = (0 0; 0 0); text = 'It's Text'; clipsToBounds = YES; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x280682700>; layer = <CALayer: 0x2808e5700>; contentOffset: {0, 0}; contentSize: {0, 40}; adjustedContentInset: {0, 0, 0, 0}>
```

Is there anyone how to solve this problem?

Comment: `frame = (0 0; 0 0)`, so it's  "invisible". I don't use SwiftUI, but I guess that you might be interested with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61832221/uiviewrepresentable-automatic-size-passing-uikit-uiview-size-to-swiftui ?

Comment: Thank you but solution in your link is not worked.. I tried to edit frame and I make it (0 0; 44 40) by sizeToFit(). But it doesn't show.. Maybe it can be other problem over this codes

Comment: add map function to updateUIView function.

Comment: Thanks but it not works. I should test same code in new project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is invoked by ScrollView.

My TextView() is wrapped by ScrollView in higher view.

You can find answer in this link -> [How to use an NSAttributedString with a ScrollView in SwiftUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59889020/how-to-use-an-nsattributedstring-with-a-scrollview-in-swiftui)